# Show $3\cos 2x + 1 = 4\cos^2 x - 2\sin^2 x$

Tags: trigonometry

Show $3\cos 2x + 1 = 4\cos^2 x - 2\sin^2 x$

Using the formula $\cos 2x = \cos x - \sin^2 x$

I can say $3\cos 2x + 1 = 3(\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x) + 1$

$\Rightarrow 3\cos x^2 - 3\sin^2 x + 1$

But from there I don't see how I can get the answer.

Comment: What's $\sin^2{x} + \cos^2{x}$?

Comment: that would equal 1

Comment: So can you replace a 1 somewhere in your last line with the expanded form?

Comment: I can't see it because $\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$ and not plus

Comment: it expands out to $3\cos x^2 - 3\sin^2 x + 1$, I still do not get where $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x$ fits in

Comment: I'll explain in an actual answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close. All you need to do is use the identity $\sin^2{x} + \cos^2{x} = 1$:

$\begin{eqnarray}3\cos{2x} + 1 & = & 3(\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}) + 1 \\
& = & 3(\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}) + \sin^2{x} + \cos^2{x} \\
& = & 4\cos^2{x} - 2\sin^2{x}
\end{eqnarray}$

QED.

Alternatively, if you don't feel comfortable turning the $1$ into $\sin^2{x}+\cos^2{x}$ (and trust me, it's a perfectly valid thing to do), you can equivalently break out one of the existing $\sin^2{x}$s and replace it with $1 - \cos^2{x}$, and as long as you get all the signs correct it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: ha!  Brilliant, I now see the light

Answer (score 3):

I continue from where you left off.

$$ 3\cos^2 x - 3\sin^2 x + 1 = 4\cos^2 x -\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x - 2\sin^2 x + 1 $$

$$ = 4\cos^2 x - 2\sin^2 x \boxed{-\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x + 1 } $$

$$ = 4\cos^2 x - 2\sin^2 x. $$